# SQL Check Constraint cannot reference other column

Tags: sql, oracle

I trying to add this sql check in

```
ALTER TABLE School
add Role check_role
  CHECK (check_role IN ('Teaching Assistant', 'Lecturer', 'Professor'));
```

I get the error below

```
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

SQL> desc School;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

 STAFFNUM                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 ADDRESS                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(300)
 DOB                                                DATE
```

I am trying add a column call Role, with the check constraint check_role

I am using Oracle SQL.

**Thanks for all help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add Role column to the table

```
 alter table School
    add (Role   varchar(10));
```

To Add constraint to the Role column.

```
alter table School
  add constraint check_role
  check (Role IN ('Teaching Assistant', 'Lecturer', 'Professor'));
```

=========

```
ALTER TABLE School ADD COLUMN Role VARCHAR(50) 
CONSTRAINT check_role CHECK 
  (Role IN ('Teaching Assistant', 'Lecturer', 'Professor'));
```