# sql Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have a table like...

```
> myConstriants;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 CODE                                               CHAR(3 CHAR)
 MIN_VALUE                                          NUMBER
 MAX_VALUE                                          NUMBER
```

and want to add a constraint like ...

```
alter table myConstriants
add constriant LAB3_EX2_CHK2
check (min_value < max_value);
```

but sql gives me...

> ERROR at line 3:
>     ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns

how do I check that the min_value is less that the max-value?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Check Constraint cannot reference other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244172/sql-check-constraint-cannot-reference-other-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misspelled:

> alter table myConstriants add **constriant** LAB3_EX2_CHK2 check
>   (min_value < max_value);

```
alter table myConstriants
add CONSTRAINT LAB3_EX2_CHK2
check (min_value < max_value);
```

**[SqlFiddlDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1451f/1/0)**

Comment: LOL.  yes I did.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Column must be not null (MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE)

Comment: will change this and check..

Comment: made the mod for both columns but get the same error.

Comment: Yes they can be null http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14b3a/3/0